# Dropping rows for an SpatialGridDataFrame object where certain conditions are met

Tags: r, dataframe, rgdal

I am operating on certain images which can have multiple bands / channels (cf. Multispectral and Hyperspectral Remote Sensing images).

Let us suppose that we do not know beforehand as to how many bands exist in the given image. All the channels are named as "band1", "band2" ... and so on. To read the image we use

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
image <- readGDAL("image.tif')
```

We take this into a `data.frame` first:

```
imdata <- image@data
```

There may be certain situations where the contents of all the bands for a particular "pixel" is zero. Therefore, if it is a four band image, then we can drop those rows from the `data.frame` by using:

```
imData <- imData[!((imData$band1==0) & (imData$band2==0) & (imData$band3 == 0) & (imData$band4 == 0)),]
```

But suppose that my image has 256 bands. How do I remove such rows from the dataset?

Comment: Not tested `imData[!Reduce('&' , imData==0),]` and maybe also `!!rowSums(imData!=0)`

Comment: I guess the first one is `imData[!Reduce(`&`,as.data.frame(imData==0))),]`

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
imData <- imData[!(rowSums(imData) == 0),]
```